# Bizarre result of shell sort?

Tags: shell, sorting

### Test 1

This code:

```
text() {
    cat <<'EOF'
f='.git_cache_meta';
f='adir/bdir/cdir/';
f='adir/';
f='he'\'''\'''\'''\'''\''s good.txt';
f='-test';
f='subdir/';
f='一份文件.txt';
f='subdir/.secret';
f='my file.txt';
f='adir/bdir/cdir/keep.txt';
f='adir/bdir/';
EOF
}

text | sort
```

outputs this:

```
f='adir/';
f='adir/bdir/';
f='adir/bdir/cdir/';
f='adir/bdir/cdir/keep.txt';
f='.git_cache_meta';
f='he'\'''\'''\'''\'''\''s good.txt';
f='my file.txt';
f='subdir/';
f='subdir/.secret';
f='-test';
f='一份文件.txt';
```

### Test 2

While this code:

```
text() {
    cat <<'EOF'
f='.git_cache_meta'; something
f='adir/bdir/cdir/'; something
f='adir/'; something
f='he'\'''\'''\'''\'''\''s good.txt'; something
f='-test'; something
f='subdir/'; something
f='一份文件.txt'; something
f='subdir/.secret'; something
f='my file.txt'; something
f='adir/bdir/cdir/keep.txt'; something
f='adir/bdir/'; something
EOF
}

text | sort
```

outputs this:

```
f='adir/bdir/cdir/keep.txt'; something
f='adir/bdir/cdir/'; something
f='adir/bdir/'; something
f='adir/'; something
f='.git_cache_meta'; something
f='he'\'''\'''\'''\'''\''s good.txt'; something
f='my file.txt'; something
f='subdir/.secret'; something
f='subdir/'; something
f='-test'; something
f='一份文件.txt'; something
```

### Problem

What I expect in the above codes is sort by ASCII code, i.e. this:

```
f='-test';
f='.git_cache_meta';
f='adir/';
f='adir/bdir/';
f='adir/bdir/cdir/';
f='adir/bdir/cdir/keep.txt';
f='he'\'''\'''\'''\'''\''s good.txt';
f='my file.txt';
f='subdir/';
f='subdir/.secret';
f='一份文件.txt';
```

and this:

```
f='-test'; something
f='.git_cache_meta'; something
f='adir/'; something
f='adir/bdir/'; something
f='adir/bdir/cdir/'; something
f='adir/bdir/cdir/keep.txt'; something
f='he'\'''\'''\'''\'''\''s good.txt'; something
f='my file.txt'; something
f='subdir/'; something
f='subdir/.secret'; something
f='一份文件.txt'; something
```

respectly.

The two test result shows that the sort doesn't follow ASCII code, and adding same value to the tail (test2) produces a very different result (in test 1 `f='adir/';` is before `f='adir/bdir/cdir/';`, while in test 2 `f='adir/'; something` is after `f='adir/bdir/cdir/'; something`).

I'd like to know what is the actual algorithm `sort` uses. And how should I code to produce the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the collation order specified in `$LC_COLLATE`. See the `locale(7)` man page for details.

```
text | LC_COLLATE=C sort
```

Comment: Thank you. It does solve the problem. My next question is what are available LC_COLLATE types, and which one is most portable and fits my expect?

Comment: The available values are "C", "POSIX", and any language installed on the system (run `locale -a` to see them). Both "C" and "POSIX" perform bytewise collation, and the others perform language-specific collation.